# directive test doesn't execute properly $http.get

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing a test in jasmine for a directive that dynamically loads templates via ajax and `$http` call. This part inside the directive looks something like this:

```
scope.load = function(templatePath) {
        $http.get(templatePath).then(function then(response) {
              // do processing here
         }).catch(function catchError() {
               // catch error
         });
}
```

and called

```
 scope.load('/path/to/template');
```

Now, this directive works just fine when used inside the browser. However, when the jasmine executes this directive, and the `load` function is called,  neither the success nor the catch blocks are ever called, and the program resumes just after the load() call. Is there any reason why this is happening ?

Comment: Are you running $digest() in test?

Comment: Did you resolve `$http.get()` promise?

Comment: don't you see .then part in the code ? it never gets called, same thing with the catch, that's the problem

Comment: Method `.then` or `.catch` will be executed when promise state will change to resolved (fulfilled).

Comment: jasmine doesnt go to a server, a colleague of mine had this same issue, he was unable to get jasmine to actually hit our server. it simply wont do it. you need to assume your server connection strings and other server issues are working and fake the result.

Answer (score 1):

Link to **AngularJS** documentation: [service/$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) - please read this. It will be helpful for understanding how to **mock** $http service. Examples are very good.

Some answer from SO to question that is close to yours:
[AngularJS - Unit test for http get to JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057522/angularjs-unit-test-for-http-get-to-json-file)

Most important method to **resolve promise `$http.get()`**:
`$httpBackend.flush();`